# VBA Many Cells into one with Array + round up

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I already managed to copy values from many cells and write them into one cell with the help of arrays.
My problem is, that I want that one cell to round up or down every value which is in that cell.

I can round up only if I write many cells into many other cells with this:

```
.Range("C2:H8").NumberFormat = "0"
```

But if I try it this way, it does not work:

```
.Range("C2").NumberFormat = "0"
```

I think the reason is that I save the values into the cell with a ",":

```
3526,13,4599,8199345,,,7599,8199345,1599,8199345
```

I do not want to have spaces between the numbers, because I save it as a csv file for statistics.

```
Call SaveIntoCell(key, .Range("C3"), 37)
Call SaveIntoCell(key, .Range("C4"), 38)
Call SaveIntoCell(key, .Range("C5"), 39)
.Range("C3").NumberFormat = "0"

Private Sub SaveIntoCell(key As String, Range As Range, row2 As String)
   Dim arr2(1 To 7) As Variant

   arr2(1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("B" & row2).Value
   arr2(2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("C" & row2).Value
   arr2(3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("D" & row2).Value
   arr2(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("G" & row2).Value
   arr2(7) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("H" & row2).Value
   Range.Value = Join(arr2, ",")
End Sub
```

Instead of

```
3526,13,4599,8199345,,,7599,8199345,1599,8199345
```

I want

```
3526,4600,,,7600,1600
```

and so on

Comment: Why not format them before joining? Don't think I get the logic of your "rounding". Why is 3526 unchanged and 4599 rounded?

Comment: @SJR .. I think the First Number is `3526.13` that Rounds to `3526` , then the next number is `4599.8199345` rounds up to `4600`

Comment: What is `Key` ?

Comment: @Mikku - I think you're right. Comma as both delimiter and decimal separator is very confusing.

Comment: @Mikku key is just a String which I wanted to add after solving my problem

Comment: @Capi .. okay ..try what I suggested in the Answer Below.

Answer (score 1):

**Try using:**

```
arr2(1) = Round(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("B" & row2).Value, 0)
```

**If the cell have `,` instead of `.` Use:**

```
arr2(1) = Round(Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("B" & row2).Value,",","."), 0)
```

Similarly for all the other Values in your Function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not work. I get "type mismatch" error.

Comment: With 1st or the 2nd or Both ?

Comment: With Both, but I found a solution

Comment: Cool ... All the Best :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had to convert it when using "Round". I converted it to double.

```
arr2(3) = Round(CDbl(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Range("C" & row).Value), 0)
```